# Implicit cast dynamic to DateTime? and op_Equality

Tags: c#, datetime, dynamic, casting

I have my own dynamic object which have to be comparable with primitive types. I defined implicit cast operators for all types I want to compare. For most of primitive types like int, short, bool, decimal implementing cast to nullable version of this types is enough for successful comparing, but not for DateTime. Did I missed some significant difference between DateTime and decimal or is it error in dynamic implementation?

```
class MyDynamic : DynamicObject
{
    public static implicit operator decimal?(MyDynamic nullable)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public static implicit operator DateTime?(MyDynamic x)
    {
        return null;
    }

    //public static implicit operator DateTime(MyDynamic x)
    //{
    //    return DateTime.MinValue;
    //}
}

[Fact]
public void FactMethodName()
{
    dynamic my = new MyDynamic();

    dynamic date = DateTime.Now;
    dynamic dec = 1m;

    Assert.False(dec == my);
    // throws
    Assert.False(date == my);
}
```

If implicit cast is not defined error message is:

```
System.InvalidOperationExceptionThe operands for operator 'Equal' do not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'.
```

stack trace is:

```
System.InvalidOperationExceptionThe operands for operator 'Equal' do not match the parameters of method 'op_Equality'.
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.GetMethodBasedBinaryOperator(ExpressionType binaryType, Expression left, Expression right, MethodInfo method, Boolean liftToNull)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Equal(Expression left, Expression right, Boolean liftToNull, MethodInfo method)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.GenerateUserDefinedBinaryOperator(EXPRCALL pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.VisitCALL(EXPRCALL pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.ExprVisitorBase.Dispatch(EXPR pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.ExprVisitorBase.Visit(EXPR pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.GenerateLambda(EXPRCALL pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.VisitCALL(EXPRCALL pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.ExprVisitorBase.Dispatch(EXPR pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.Semantics.ExprVisitorBase.Visit(EXPR pExpr)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.ExpressionTreeCallRewriter.Rewrite(TypeManager typeManager, EXPR pExpr, IEnumerable`1 listOfParameters)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.CreateExpressionTreeFromResult(IEnumerable`1 parameters, ArgumentObject[] arguments, Scope pScope, EXPR pResult)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.BindCore(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, ref DynamicMetaObject deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder payload, IEnumerable`1 parameters, DynamicMetaObject[] args, ref DynamicMetaObject deferredBinding)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.BinderHelper.Bind(DynamicMetaObjectBinder action, RuntimeBinder binder, IEnumerable`1 args, IEnumerable`1 arginfos, DynamicMetaObject onBindingError)
   at Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.CSharpBinaryOperationBinder.FallbackBinaryOperation(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject arg, DynamicMetaObject errorSuggestion)
   at System.Dynamic.BinaryOperationBinder.FallbackBinaryOperation(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject arg)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObject.BindBinaryOperation(BinaryOperationBinder binder, DynamicMetaObject arg)
   at System.Dynamic.BinaryOperationBinder.Bind(DynamicMetaObject target, DynamicMetaObject[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.DynamicMetaObjectBinder.Bind(Object[] args, ReadOnlyCollection`1 parameters, LabelTarget returnLabel)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallSiteBinder.BindCore(CallSite`1 site, Object[] args)
   at System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2<T0,T1,TRet>(CallSite site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1)
```

In most cases my custom dynamic should act almost as null, so casting to value type is unwanted.

Comment: Unfortunately the *exact* details of how dynamic binding work aren't clearly documented in the spec. The fact that it works for `decimal` but not `DateTime` is odd though. Does it work if you *don't* use `dynamic`, e.g. if you use `var` for all those variables?

Comment: If both "my" and "date" variables are not dynamic (no call site is involved) then it works as expected.

Comment: In that case it *feels* like it's a bug in the dynamic handling to me. I try to keep these things as simple (and rare) as possible :(

Answer (score 0):

defining operator == keep code simpler.

```
public static bool operator ==(MyDynamic lhs, object rhs)
{
    if (rhs is MyDynamic)
        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    else
        return false;
}
public static bool operator !=(MyDynamic lhs, object rhs)
{
    if (rhs is MyDynamic)
        return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
    else
        return true;
}

public static bool operator ==(object lhs, MyDynamic rhs)
{
    if (lhs is MyDynamic)
        return lhs.Equals(rhs);
    else
        return false;
}
public static bool operator !=(object lhs, MyDynamic rhs)
{
    if (lhs is MyDynamic)
        return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
    else
        return true;
}
```

**EDIT**
I explicitly implement both (MyDynamic == object) and (object == MyDynamic). because overriding TryBinaryOperation() couldn't caught (object == MyDynamic) case.

```
public override bool TryBinaryOperation(BinaryOperationBinder binder, object arg, out object result) 
{
    if (binder.Operation == System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType.Equal) { ... }

    return base.TryBinaryOperation(binder, arg, out result);
}
```

Comment: I've tried this, here you have ambiguous error. Your code with my sample:
Additional information: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.DateTime.operator ==(System.DateTime, System.DateTime)' and 'ConsoleApplication11.MyDynamic.operator ==(object, ConsoleApplication11.MyDynamic)'

Comment: You probably forget removing 'public static implicit operator DateTime?(MyDynamic x)'.

Comment: Yes, ambigous error gone if we compare dynamics, but appears if we compare with null: Assert.True(null != my); Anyway thank you for your answer, It is valuable workaround in some situations.